# How could i extend internal Gruntjs templater functionality?

Tags: javascript, templates, md5, gruntjs, config

I would like **to add custom templater** functionality,
like: replace "word://path/" construction to "config.param.word" value from options,
or **add an implementation of md5** checksum to templater.

For example i want to get "/word/path/value/ce0c8f5d2b4b6ca4e73f5b0595817606.min.js" 
instead of: `"src":"word://<%= md5( /path/ )%>.min.js"`

What is the best way to do this?
It can be done with gruntjs source refactor, but it's not a good idea.
Maybe i can use some callback etc?

It's not a problem to get md5 or to replace a string, but i'm not sure what is the right way to change internal gruntjs methods like **grunt.config.process**.

**UPD:**

If u want to use md5 in Gruntfile.js, u could use it like this etc:
*Gruntfile.js:*

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
var common = require('./common.js');
// Grunt tasks
grunt.config.init({
    md5: function( s ){ return common.md5( s ) },
```

Than i get this code of [js-md5](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-md5.html) , wrap it by:

```
exports.md5 = function( string ) {
 //external code from link 
}
```

and save to common.js;

After that the usage will be etc:
`src:'<%= md5("/file/path/filename.ext") %>.min.js'`

Comment: Seems like host objects augmentation... (I actually +1ed you, as I would love to know the answer as well).

Is there any documentation on that usage of `init`?

Comment: The gruntjs developer answered to me on this [page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1011). Maybe u'll found it useful.